# Erro em procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

Eu criei essa `procedure` para testar se existe um campo em um banco de dados, se caso não existir, a `procedure` iria criar.

```
  DELIMITER ||

    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_verificarLinhas(IN colunas VARCHAR(50))     BEGIN 
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = Database() AND TABLE_NAME='prt_license' AND COLUMN_NAME
    = colunas )         THEN        SET @s = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE eco_portaldb.prt_license ADD COLUMN ', colunas ,' VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER date_update');          PREPARE stmt FROM @s;       EXECUTE stmt;

       end if;   END ||

    DELIMITER ;
```

Quando encontra algum campo que não exista, ele me da o seguinte erro:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1142 ALTER command denied to user
>   'eco_portaluserh'@'186.206.156.42' for table 'prt_license'

Após de remove-la e tentar recria-la, começou a me dar esse erro:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations
>   (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for
>   operation '='

**esse pedaço já foi corrigido transformando o banco de dados em general**

O banco de dados, a tabela estão como `UTF8`. Já tentei:

```
alter table `prt_license` convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel, o usúario `eco_portaluserh` não possuí permissão para executar o comando `ALTER`, você precisa executar um `GRANT` utilizando um usuário com nível de permissão.

dessa forma:

```
GRANT ALTER ON database.* TO 'username'@'interface' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Onde :

1. database: nome da database aonde esse usúario terá acesso.
2. username: é igual a `eco_portaluserh`
3. interface: é igual a `186.206.156.42`
4. password: é igual a senha desse usuário, definida na criação de conta.

Após executar o comando acima dê :

```
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Para atualizar as permissões do usúario no mysql.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Errar é humano, mas dessa vez tenho certeza sim. Acabei de testar conforme a imagem acima.

Você está tentando dar permissão ao usuário `eco_portaluserh` logado no mysql com ele mesmo. Ele não tem privilégios sobre sua database `eco_portaldb_homolog`. Você deve usar um outro usuário no caso da imagem, usei meu usuário `root` que tem todas as permissões sobre todas as minhas databases, repare que devido ao fato do usúario `root` ter acesso a todos as databases, eu defini ele como `localhost` que nada mais é, que a interface de rede 127.0.0.1; ou seja acesso apenas local para manter a segurança.

Comment: Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'eco_portaluserh'@'%' to database 'eco_portaldb_homolog'


Executando o comando me deu o seguinte erro

Comment: O usuário que está usando para executar o comando não tem permissão! Você tem efetuar login e executar o comando acima com um usuário que tenha privilégio para isso.

Comment: Cara, certeza que o problema da procedure é de permissão? não tem nenhum erro de sql não?